# bypassing permission error for a plugin's page

Tags: errors, permissions

i'm getting "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" error when trying to go to a plugin's settings. there's only one user which is the admin and has full access.

this is the URL i'm getting this error on:

store/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wpb_vc_settings

i tried to find the if statements which was about that error, like this:

```
if (!current_user_can('manage_options'))  {
        wp_die( __('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.') );
    }
```

and commented them, yet that error appeared again. even tried to delete the whole statement, nothing changed. I've searched through all the codes of the plugin with Dreamweaver but they weren't anywhere else.
i'm looking for a way to bypass this.

Answer (score 0):

While there can be checks inside page the page itself is added via API call, like [`add_options_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page) (there are several analogous functions that add pages to different parts of admin).

This call includes capability argument. In your case either the extension in question is poorly coded and does something strange around there or your user is somehow corrupted (unlikely if you are not seeing similar errors all over admin).